# How to access i2c device driver node

Tags: linux, i2c

### Situation 1:

I have an i2c chip driver as part of linux kernel. I can verify the i2c chip driver is in the kernel from kernel boot messages (my chip driver is mma8450)

dmesg:

```
mma8450 0-001c: uevent
```

I can also see this driver in (0x1c is i2c address of chip)

```
cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-001c/name
mma8450
```

I can not see this driver node in /dev interface. My question is how can I create node of this device in /dev so that I can access this device in a user program ?

### Situation 2:

I create the module of the same chip driver and does not make it a part of kernel. I can load this module using insmod mma8450, how can I create a node of this device as I don't have its major / minor numbers ? (I can not see major & minor numbers assigned to this driver in mma8450 source code)

Any help is appreciated

Regards

Comment: do you know about the sensors-detect script? I use it on Ubuntu and it probably part of Debian. It will detect and load proper modules; never had a problem with it yet

Answer (score 4):

Load the kernel module:

modprobe i2c-dev

```
ls /dev/i2*

/dev/i2c-0  
/dev/i2c-10  
/dev/i2c-12  
/dev/i2c-14  
/dev/i2c-3  
/dev/i2c-5  
/dev/i2c-7  
/dev/i2c-9
/dev/i2c-1  
/dev/i2c-11  
/dev/i2c-13  
/dev/i2c-2   
/dev/i2c-4  
/dev/i2c-6  
/dev/i2c-8
```

Comment: this command creates device nodes for the I2C bus (controller). Question was is it possible to create device nodes for mma8450 I2C client.

Answer (score 3):

Find the major/minor numbers for your device:

```
cat /proc/devices
```

You should see a device for the i2c bus and one for the i2c device itself.

Create the device node for the i2c device driver:

```
mknod /dev/[device name] [type] [major] [minor]
```

Comment: I think there is only I2C bus device listed under character devices. not the mma8450 I2C client.

Answer (score 1):

This is 3-Axis Accelerometer. Linux registers it as a driver for `input_polled_dev` type.

You can uaccess it using /dev/i2c-x bus (controller) device node, but there is no much sense using it that way directly from userspace.

I2C clients are not meant to be used using /dev device nodes.
They should be registered to Kernel I2C framework and used through higher layers API.

There is sample program for reading similar MMA7455L x,y,z registers from userspace using /dev/i2c-X bus device node.

[Reading the Accelerometer With I²C](https://guy.carpenter.id.au/chumby-oe/blog/2012/03/20/reading-the-accelerometer-with-i2c/)